# Problems importing with Mongodb: fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

Tags: mongodb, go, macos-sierra

I'm running into a fatal error when I'm trying to import using Mongodb 3.3.9. My script has worked before, but when I upgraded my Mac os to Sierra, I'm running into what looks like a Go language problem.

Error received :

fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

> runtime stack: runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0x491d30, 0x54daf0)
>     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f
>   runtime.MHeap_Alloc(0x491cc0, 0x2, 0x10000000026, 0xdbc9)
>     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:240 +0x66
>   runtime.MCentral_CacheSpan(0x49b0b8, 0x34872)
>     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.c:85 +0x167
>   runtime.MCache_Refill(0x527c20, 0xc200000026, 0x5550b8)
>     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcache.c:90 +0xa0

Others have noted a similar problem that was supposed to be resolved in an earlier version ([mongorestore random crash (fatal error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719882/mongorestore-random-crash-fatal-error/39733084)), but my problem persists.

Comment: You need to rebuild your binaries with a current version of Go to support Sierra.

Comment: May I ask how? Sorry I'm new to this and unfamiliar with dealing with binaries.

Comment: I assumed you built the program, since you're asking on a programming forum. If you can't recompile the Go program, you need to get an updated version.

Comment: This has nothing to do with go, but with your need to update homebrew mongo after your os upgrade. I suggest `brew upgrade mongodb`.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggested, it's solved reinstalling mongo. If you install it using `brew` execute: `brew uninstall mongo`.

If you just followed the steps in their tutorial, just delete the executable. If you don't know how, follow this:

```
which mongo
#now you have a path
rm -rf yourMongoPath
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.ntp.ntpd.plist

worked for me

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that